# How abort thread when QMainWindow is closed?

Tags: multithreading, pyqt5, popup

In this MWE, a popup window is created and after 8 seconds it prints 'done' in the console.
If the popup window is closed before 'done' is printed, then after a few seconds it still prints 'done'.
I would like that nothing is printed if I close the popup window before 'done' is printed. How can do this?

```
import time
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
import threading

class CustomMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomMainWindow, self).__init__()
        myDataLoop = threading.Thread(name = 'myDataLoop', target = dataSendLoop, daemon = True, args = ())
        myDataLoop.start()
        self.show()
        return

def dataSendLoop():
    #actually a lengthy calculation
    time.sleep(8)
    print('done')

if __name__== '__main__':
    app =QApplication(sys.argv)
    myGUI = CustomMainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Use [QTimer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html).

Comment: @musicamante, actually I want to calculate a lot of things instead of the time.sleep(8) command, but to change it to a MWE I used time.sleep(8).

Comment: Then it depends on how that "lengthy calculation" is done. If it uses a for loop or can be "step-based", you could make it an instance that can be referred, create an internal flag that periodically checks if the computation should continue, and eventually unset that flag when the window is closed by overriding the `closeEvent()`.